# JQuery - Problem with selectors (siblings, parents...)

Tags: coldfusion, jquery-selectors, siblings, parents

I got a coldfusion query where the result is grouped on country names. With a click on this one, I try to open or close the list under the country. But i cannot work correctly with this siblings and this parents. The result is, if i click on a country name, the fourth one, for example, it close all childrens, and the three country name which are before too.
Can someone help me to choose the right selectors ? 
Thank you in advance ,
Michel

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var toggleMinus = '<cfoutput>#variables.strWebAddress#</cfoutput>/images/bullet_toggle_minus.png';
        var togglePlus = '<cfoutput>#variables.strWebAddress#</cfoutput>/images/bullet_toggle_plus.png';
        var $subHead = $('table#categorylist tbody th:first-child');
        $subHead.prepend('<img src="' +toggleMinus+ '" alt="collapse this section" />&nbsp;');
        $('img', $subHead).addClass('clickable').click(function(){
            var toggleSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            if(toggleSrc == toggleMinus){
               $(this).attr('src',togglePlus).parents('.country').siblings().fadeOut('fast');
            }else{
              $(this).attr('src',toggleMinus).parents('.country').siblings().fadeIn('fast');
            }
        });
     }); 
</script>

<table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center id="categorylist"> 
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text3" width="15%">
            <cfmodule template="../custom_tags/get_message.cfm" keyName="L_ACTOR_CODENUMBER">
        </th>
        <th class="text3" width="15%">
            <cfmodule template="../custom_tags/get_message.cfm" keyName="L_ACTOR_CODE">
        </th>
        <th class="text3" width="55%">
            <cfmodule template="../custom_tags/get_message.cfm" keyName="L_ACTOR_NAME">
        </th>
        <th class="text3" width="15%">
            <cfmodule template="../custom_tags/get_message.cfm" keyName="L_ACTIVE">
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="content">
<cfoutput query="qryCategoryUrl" group="country_name" groupcasesensitive="false">
    <tr class="country">
        <th style="font-weight:bold; text-align:left;" colspan="4">#country_name#</th>
    </tr>
<cfoutput>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="text3">#Replace(ACTOR_CODENUMBER, Chr(13) & Chr(10), "<br>", "ALL")#&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top" class="text3">#Replace(ACTOR_CODE, Chr(13) & Chr(10), "<br>", "ALL")#&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top" class="text3">#Replace(ACTOR_NAME, Chr(13) & Chr(10), "<br>", "ALL")#&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top" class="text3"><cfmodule template="../custom_tags//get_message.cfm" keyName="#ACTIVE_display(qryCategoryUrl.ACTIVE)#"></td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a bit difficult to replicate as you've got integrated templates and server-side code.  Can you update the code sample with the generated HTML?  This way your situation can be replicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.parents('.country').siblings().fadeOut('fast');
```

Try this:

```
.closest('.country').nextUntil('.country').fadeOut('fast');
```

And of course, apply the same change to the `.fadeIn()`. You might also look into [`.fadeToggle()`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).

Here's a (reduced) example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/5sqJz/. While it doesn't affect the example, presumably you would be setting the initial state of those detail rows as hidden.

Comment: Thank you Ken, this is the solution. Only one little problem yet, I have the first time to click two times on the line to toggle it. Do you know why ?

Comment: I tried with fadeToggle and the 'two times click' problem is gone.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and hank you to Brian too.

Answer (score 0):

woah all that cfmodule usage, cfmodule can be a memory hog.

Although what I always recommend is that people try their pages in whatever browser, and use the SelectorGadget bookmarklet at http://www.selectorgadget.com/

This makes it easier to test and check the correct selector, for your app needs.